# Malformed geometry when saving valid GeoJSON in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, geojson, php-mongodb

I make up a GeoJSON object for my MongoDB's `2dsphere` index like so (in PHP):

```
array (size=2)
  'type' => string 'Point' (length=5)
  'coordinates' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => float 45
      1 => float 95
```

Except this does not work in MongoDB, returning an error of:

```
Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry
```

Why cannot not save this valid GeoJSON point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because 95 is not a valid latitude.

You must, in your application, validate the values of your point against the range of latitude and longitude points as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743805/383478

> The valid range of latitude in degrees is -90 and +90 for the southern and northern hemisphere respectively. Longitude is in the range -180 and +180 specifying the east-west position.

Otherwise MongoDB will fail with a write exception when the user enters some data that is not actually valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the wrong lat/long values. As [per documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/#geospatial-indexes-range):

> By default, a 2d index assumes longitude and latitude and has
>   boundaries of -180 inclusive and 180 non-inclusive. If documents
>   contain coordinate data outside of the specified range, MongoDB
>   returns an error.

But for lat this behavior is not defined

> IMPORTANT The default boundaries allow applications to insert
>   documents with invalid latitudes greater than 90 or less than -90. The
>   behavior of geospatial queries with such invalid points is not
>   defined.

And most probably this is just php driver which enforces it (and I think it is good).