# How to get user location using models in django

Tags: python, django, api, location, backend

so I am looking a way to receive users location when user will submit the location and other fields from map then it should send the location in lng and lat so I can check the location of the user.... Like uber ola does

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data from a device then check the native capabilities for this.

Flutter for example has a package:

- https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator
  Android has its native libraries:
- https://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

#### Stackoverflow answers for this:

[Which Model Field to use in Django to store longitude and latitude values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706799/which-model-field-to-use-in-django-to-store-longitude-and-latitude-values)

#### official django docs for this:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geographic-models
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/