# MongoDB 'unable to create 2dsphere index and find index for $geoNear query in

Tags: java, php, mongodb

My collection

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("58240d6eb3fe299a1f28bdf0"),
    "id" : NumberLong(52),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "user_type" : "user",
    "type_id" : "399278",
    "type" : "poi",
    "type_name" : "Kala Ghoda Amphitheatre",
    "attending" : NumberLong(0),
    "domain" : "",
    "track_time" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "latitude" : "18.92728500",
    "longitude" : "72.83274200",
    "fb_postid" : "",
    "event_date" : "0000-00-00",
    "m_event_date" : NumberLong("-62169984000"),
    "m_type_id" : "poi__399278",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            18.927285,
            72.832742
        ]
    }
```

Create index
**db.user_tracking.ensureIndex({ "loc": "2dsphere" })**

I have this error:

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('58240d6eb3fe299a1f28bdf1'), id: 84, user_id: 2, user_type: \"wcities\", type_id: \"23621\", type: \"poi\", type_name: \"Alcatraz Island\", attending: 1, domain: \"Parrot\", track_time: \"2015-02-02 06:33:34\", latitude: \"37.82668800\", longitude: \"-122.42302500\", fb_postid: \"\", event_date: \"0000-00-00\", m_event_date: -62169984000, m_type_id: \"poi__23621\", loc: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 37.826688, -122.423025 ] } }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 37.8267 lat: -122.423",
"code" : 16755
}
```

Comment: First Think  when you create collection remember coordinates[<longitude>,<latitude>] ok.Not coordinates[<latitude>,<longitude>]

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all `longitude/latitude is out of bounds`

just see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965166/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-latitude-and-longitude) for the range allowed. your latitude of `lng: 37.8267 lat: -122.423` goes beyond the range of +90/-90 . You need to correct that document which have this data.

More on [geoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/geojson/#geojson-point)