# Error with openweathermap API

Tags: python, python-3.x, weather-api, openweathermap

I am trying to have current weather data by latitude and longitude. Here is a part of my Python code:

```
import requests

def get_weather(lat, lon):
    return requests.get(f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon},fr&appid=<MY API KEY>').json()

print(get_weather(96.95, 21.83))
```

It returns this:

```
{"cod":"400","message":"96.95 is not a float"}
```

Do you know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message will occur when the provided latitude or longitude is out of range. A latitude of 96.95 is not within the valid latitude range.

> Latitudes range from -90 to 90. Longitudes range from -180 to 180.
>
> range source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16743805/1816667

Answer (score 1):

**Problem fixed !**

The problem was the url:

```
f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon},fr&appid=<MY API KEY>'
```

The correct one is:

```
f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid=<MY API KEY>'
```